# Changing Order of When to Count Characters

Tags: string, count, character, python-2.x

I've got code that currently takes a huge string from a file. It counts an occurrence of a particular string "GCAA" and returns how many times it appears. Then, it replaces certain characters through a maptrans. Then it re-counts how many times that string "GCAA" appears. Lastly, it reverses the entire file/contents. What my problem is now, is that I want to change the order of a few things that are happening but I can't seem to do it. I want to REVERSE the contents first. THEN replace the letters as such. And lastly, re-count "GCAA" after the reverse+replace. (still keeping the first count before anything happens the same).

[EDIT]: FIGURED IT OUT!!

Current code:

```
# Code to count occurrence of 'GCAA' before letter switching
g = open("filename.txt", "r")
input2 = g.read()
print(input2.count('GCAA'))
g.close()

# Code to SWITCH all the letters AND count occurence of 'GCAA' after
from string import maketrans
table = maketrans("GCTA", "CGAT")
f = open("filename.txt", "r")
input = f.read()
print(input.translate(table))

result = input.translate(table)
print(result.count('GCAA'))

# Reverse the whole thing
print(result[::-1] )

f.close()
```

Basically, keep the first part where it counts the same. But then I want to REVERSE first. Then as it's reversed, then replace the letters as such. And after both of those items are done one after another, then lastly, re-count again.

Comment: Nevermind, I was just able to figure it out! Basically, I had to set another variable for result[::-1] and then call with it afterwards. Then I was able to reverse first, then replace letters, then re-count.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out; I edited the question/comment above and indicated this as well.
Thanks to all those who may have posted an eventual answer as well.